# Get iteration in $.each using assosiative array

Tags: jquery, json, iteration, each

JSON:

```
{
    "bk00001": {
        "path": "books/bk00001/",
        "lang": "ar",
        "title": [
            "Book 1",
            "Book 1"
        ]
    },
    "bk00002": {
        "path": "books/bk00002/",
        "lang": "ar",
        "title": [
            "Book 2",
            "Book 2"
        ]
    }
}
```

jQuery:

```
$.getJSON(catalog, function(data, status) {
    var items = [];
    $.each( data, function( id, meta ) {
        items.push( "<li class='" + id + "'>" + meta.path + "</li>" );
        items.push( "<li class='" + id + "'>" + meta.lang + "</li>" );
        items.push( "<li class='" + id + "'>" + meta.title + "</li>" );
    });

    $( "<ul/>", {
        "id": "library",
        html: items.join( "" )
    }).appendTo( "body" );

});
```

.. but the output is not what I expect, thats because `id` returned is actually the key of the object, not an index of the loop.

This is the **expected** output:

```
<ul id="library">
    <ul id="bk00001">
        <li class="path">...</li>
        <li class="lang">...</li>
        <li class="title">...</li>
        ...
    </ul>
    <ul id="bk00002">
        <li class="path">...</li>
        <li class="lang">...</li>
        <li class="title">...</li>
        ...
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why do you expect `id` to be equal `"path"`, `"lang"`, & `"title"`, and all that without changing id?

Comment: @Amit Updated the description with the JSON I'm working with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless there's any special reason NOT to do the simple thing, this is what you want:

```js
//...
//...
$.each( data, function( id, meta ) {
        items.push( "<ul id='" + id + "'>");
        items.push( "<li class='path'>" + meta.path + "</li>" );
        items.push( "<li class='lang'>" + meta.lang + "</li>" );
        items.push( "<li class='title'>" + meta.title + "</li>" );
        items.push( "</ul>");
    });
//...
//...
```

Comment: Oh HECK! It was so simple, I couldn't see it! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

From the [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

> If an object is used as the collection, the callback is passed a
>   key-value pair each time:

Here's what I would do:

```
$.getJSON(catalog, function(data, status) {
    var library = $("<ul id='library'/>");
    $.each( data, function( id, meta ) {
        var ul = $("<ul id='" + id + "'/>");
        ul.append( "<li class='path'>" + meta.path + "</li>" );
        ul.append( "<li class='lang'>" + meta.lang + "</li>" );
        ul.append( "<li class='title'>" + meta.title + "</li>" );
        library.append(ul);
    });

    library.appendTo("body");
});
```